# SWF being cached even with unique query string

Tags: asp.net, flash, apache-flex, http-caching

When we reference a SWF file from our ASP.NET page we append the version number to the SWF url, like `App.swf?1.1.0.0`.  In a recent update, Firefox has continued to use a cached swf even when the version number changed, `App.swf?1.2.0.0`.  We haven't noticed this behavior in other browsers.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  We don't want to disable caching completely.  At this point we're probably going to change the name of the swf for each version, like `App.1.2.0.0.swf`, which seems a bit excessive.

Thanks,

Comment: I find the latter solution to not be excessive.  I actually find it a better way of doing things because you have a clearer idea of which swf you're loading, plus it can conform to Maven standard (artifactid-version.type).  With that said however, I'm sure William's answer below will work unless there is a massive bug within Firefox.

Comment: The other benefit of changing the name or the path (which is perhaps better) is that intermediate proxies will be able to cache the file. Pretty much any proxy server won't cache URLs with ?... in them

Comment: @Andy Davies, good point.  We're going with that option.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried App.swf?version=1.1.0.0 rather than just App.swf?1.1.0.0 ?

Comment: @William, thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but it did not solve the issue.